# Spotipy redirect uri opening on server instead of users browser?

Tags: python, django, heroku, spotify

I built a web app using Django and the wrapper for the Spotify api, Spotipy, and deployed it to Heroku. The problem I am facing is that the redirect uri opens on the machine running the code, which in this case is the linux server used by heroku. Because of this, the user never actually sees the page prompting them to authenticate the app and login to their Spotify accounts, resulting in a request timeout from Heroku. This happens when my `REDIRECT_URI` is set to `http://localhost/`. I have tried to set the `REDIRECT_URI` to `https://nameofmyapp.herokuapp.com` which then resulted in an `EOFError` from the Spotipy module. I have not been able to find a solution for this. For context, my authentication flow is set up as follows:

```
def index(request):
    cache_handler = spotipy.DjangoSessionCacheHandler(request=request)
    auth_manager = spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOAuth(
        env("CLIENT_ID"), env("CLIENT_SECRET"), env("REDIRECT_URI"), scope=env("SCOPE"), cache_handler=cache_handler)
    session = spotipy.Spotify(
        oauth_manager=auth_manager, requests_session=True)
```

Comment: Someone else had a problem with spotipy when they did add a port number to the redirect url, so I think you should add one.